# I have added port to firewalld but ECONNREFUSED will return every time I send a request

Tags: centos, firewalld, port

I'm working on Centos7 VPS and I have added  port 9200 to `firewalld`, but I can not request this port and I will get this error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED` from Postman.

My firewall status:

```
> firewall-cmd --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 8420/tcp 9200/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

active zones status:

```
> firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```

default zone:

```
> firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
public
```

My `interfaces` parameter is empty, is this ok?

Comment: Yes,  i did multiple times

Comment: I will connect via ssh, and those are ```golang``` applications.
```ssh root@ip --vvv``` will return a really long list, is this helpful to mention here ?

Comment: guys I  think some misunderstanding has happened, I connect with ssh with no problems, my problem is that I can not to request to my application from browser or postman, and I will get this error ```Error: connect ECONNREFUSED```

Comment: sorry for that, I thought it was clear :)

Comment: Is the application running that listens to the port?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326929/117549

Comment: yes they are listening

Comment: Are they listening on a public port?  What is the output of `ss -tlp | grep 9200`?

Comment: Yes They are listening

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not the Firewalld. 
Port 9200 belongs to ElasticSearch 
Elasticsearch by default has some security thing that does not allow access to it from other IPs except local IPs.
So I edit the elasticsearch.yml file and the problem was solved.